# WordPress ACF Plugin to Rest API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Is there a way to add the fields of ACF to WordPress JSON API? I want to create a WooCommerce Shop with additional fields and make the front-end with Vuejs, these additional fields must then logically appear in the WordPress JSON API. But they don't.

There is a plugin (https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api/) but it is very outdated and does not seem to be usable anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expose all the ACF fields to Wordpress REST API in both pages and custom postypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473929/how-to-expose-all-the-acf-fields-to-wordpress-rest-api-in-both-pages-and-custom)

Comment: Yes! After some trial and error and a stupid mistake on my part it now works. Thank you.