# Expose ACF Users fields in WordPress API

Tags: wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api, php-7.3, acfpro

I have the latest WordPress version and PHP 7.3
I would like to use the API that is available since 4.7 as long as I read.
For now, I have installed the ACF Pro and I have **added some custom fields in Users**

But my problem is that these custom fields does not appear in API
I would prefer not to use any plug-ins  (if it is not nessasery in order to have a stable code, rather than updates and plug-ins covering other plug-ins.. and so on.. ), but of course if this is the only and easier way, let's go we that!

I have done so far "How to expose all the ACF fields to Wordpress REST API in both pages and custom postypes" 
through another post here in overflow: [How to expose all the ACF fields to Wordpress REST API in both pages and custom postypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473929/how-to-expose-all-the-acf-fields-to-wordpress-rest-api-in-both-pages-and-custom)
which it was also helpful for other reasons.

I have already installed **ACF to REST API - v3** plugin, but I do not know the next steps.. Custom fields still does not appear yet. what should I do after that?

Furthermore, I have tried and installed "JSON API User" but I think I am missing something..

Could you give me some explanations how all these works, and steps to continue? I would like to have my custom fields of Users available to API (fields I have like classes, sectiones, PIN and so on)

Comment: Hey Kiriakos, Are you able to see the "acf" object to the JSON API Response?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.. I see that, if I grab the link that gives me https://www.example.com/wp-json/acf/v3/users and get the users I get the acf object but it is empty for subscribers... For admins and editors I get the custom values!! I just saw it.. what about the subscribers and other users level?

Comment: I think the API does not require any access level for pulled-out the custom field values. Can you confirm whether the subscriber role user custom field value is updated to CMS?

Comment: Hello Jenil! I found something but really strange.. I have imported these users through WP All Import Pro plugin.. and now I just edit one of the users and just hit save. after that the information of this user displayed normally .. Just now I did a simple save to all of them and worked.. But why is that? guess it is a bug of import plugin? ... never know

Comment: Hi Kiriakos, I don't think so this is a bug of WP All Import Pro, As the value is appearing properly to CMS as you mentioned. I also faced the same issue before with different case and update post workaround help me :)
You can raise this concern to WP All Import Pro help-desk, they might helpful for this.

Thanks