# Publish ACF fields to REST API for Users

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I have published ACF fields to the REST API for various post types but I fail doing the same for Users. The response I get from /wp/v2/users/me is:

```
{
 ... 
 "ACF": false,
 ...
}
```

I have used the this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/56473974/4926772